# Writing to boost shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

It must have been straight forward answer, but I haven't found anywhere how to do it...

I have successfully created a shared memory segment using boost IPC system as in the example:

```
boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

sharedData = segment.construct<MyType>("Test")(0, 0.2);
```

I have also been able to read the values from a different process. What I cannot understand is how to edit the values of this variable (If I'm allowed to call "Test" as a variable) and read them from the other process. I want to be on a loop and write these values.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a good idea because there is no way of enforcing concurrency on a shared memory block. In the same way a shared resource needs to be protected from multiple threads crashing into each other (e.g. with a mutex or critical section) the same is true for a shared memory block.

Without an extra signalling mechanism using something like named pipes, there is no way of safely signalling that a shared memory block is

- available to read
- available to write
- updated

If you create your memory block with the `read_write` flag it will set the correct Windows permissions. The example in the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory) shows this.

```
using boost::interprocess;
shared_memory_object shm_obj
   (open_only                    //only open
   ,"shared_memory"              //name
   ,read_write                   //read-write mode
   );
```

Comment: I don't need it for a time critical application. I will be updating the values at most 10 times a second. I don't expect there will be a problem, or will it?

Comment: How does one application know when the other has started or finished reading or writing? You will run likely run into problems quickly.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think I've already been there. I was hoping boost will handle these issues. I've also tried using the read_write way, but I can't compile it under Ubuntu. Thx for your comments anyway.

Comment: No problem :-) Boost is great but in this case it is only a thin wrapper over the OS shared memory implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Konrad suggested, using shared memory so loosely is not A Good Thing™. That being said, Boost does provide interprocess synchronization utilities that work much the same as those traditionally used between threads.

Give [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html) page of the documentation a good read (particularly the section on Conditions) and see if that might give you an idea of what should be aiming for.